# Push to talk based on Ip address apps android

Tags: wifi

I want to develop an android app which uses push to talk or Voip to communicate between 2 mobile devices using a Wi-Fi connection without using a data or the internet.

Is it possible to develop this?

I am looking for a 'free' Wi-Fi Walkie Talkie but I don't know how to start doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very simple, initial version, I'd do the following:

- Assign a static IP address on each phone
- Record the audio and packetise it into a UDP stream that you'll send to the remote IP address
- Repackage again the UDP stream and play the audio.

Microphone ---> Samples ----> UDP (over WiFi) ----> Samples ----> Speaker.

There are plenty of enhancements that you can add over the time:

- Device discovery
- Signalling separate (SIP or custom messages via TCP or UDP to indicate when to start the audio transmission and negotiate the media channel that will be used).
- Support for third party devices (SIP)
- Use standard paketization using RTP and encode the audio using G711alaw/G711ulaw...

There are plenty options, but you should start by capturing the audio, and sending it over the network, even make packets of 2 seconds with the incurring delay, but that's a point to start. Then, you should lower the packet length to contain 20ms of audio to avoid delays in the transmission.

Hope this helps.